# How to create a QList with fix indices

Tags: c++, qt, list

I want to have a QList in which the Elements are still at their positions when deleting one.
So its like a List with holes or sth. like that.

Comment: QLinkedList doesn't even have random access, or indices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `QMap<int, your_type>`.

Comment: The `QHash<int, you_type>` is also an option.

Comment: `QHash` traverses in hash-order, which is random. If he cares for indices, chances are he wants index-order.

Answer (score 2):

There are different options with different semantics available:

1. `QMap<int, T>`: "Holes" do not exist at all. Accessing a hole results in a default value / not exist.
2. `QVector<T>`: Holes exist as null- or default-constructed values. This requires null-semantics from `T`. This works well with many Qt types like `QString`, `QDateTime`, they all have the concept of a null value (=> `isNull()`).
3. `QVector<T*>`: Holes are `nullptr`s. This works very well if you have a pure "pointer type", e.g. `QObject`-derived `T`.
4. `QHash<int, T>`: Basically the same idea as option 1), but take care: `QHash` traverses items in hash-order, which is completly random, while `QMap` traverses items in index-order defined by the <-Relation on the key type (`int`)!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `list with holes` why not consider `QVector` of pointers to your objects(`QVector<MyCustomType*> myListWithHoles;`)?...Assuming that by a `hole` you mean an object which memory was released a `QVector` of pointers keeps the positions of each item even though you destroy some of them and you still have access to the memory of each item.